# Sprite Kit (swift) node friction - screen jumping

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2

I'm making my first game, in the picture the player is one the edge of a block, the left side of the block is slightly curved and the right is straight (I don't know if that matters - but seems to make a difference)

When the layer is at the very left position the screen jumps up and down as if the player is confused as to which part of the block its attached to.

I try to move but the player is stuck (unless I jump) this also happens on the right of the block, but the screen does not jump like the right (must be the curve?).

I assume its something to do with friction but the friction for the Block is set as zero.

How do I fix this?

Here is the class for the block:

```
import SpriteKit

class Tile: SKSpriteNode
{
  var textureAtlas:SKTextureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named:"Tiles.atlas")

  func spawn(parentNode:SKNode, position:CGPoint, size:CGSize = CGSize(width: 48, height: 48), texture_id: Int = 1)
  {
    parentNode.addChild(self)

    self.size = size
    self.position = position
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height))
    self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false;
    self.physicsBody?.dynamic=false
    //self.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    self.texture = textureAtlas.textureNamed("\(texture_id).png");

    if texture_id == 17 {
        //self.physicsBody?.friction = 0;
        self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ground.rawValue
    }
}
```

This is part of the class for the player:

```
    self.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 1.0
    self.physicsBody?.mass = 84
    self.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.penguin.rawValue
    self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.enemy.rawValue
```

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you turn off damping and remove the mass property? I'd start there and see if your result is better.

Comment: I removed those - he now fly's off into the air if I jump! - So there are no special functions to fix this? I just have to play around with the numbers?

Comment: I would use the `physicsBody.applyImpulse` property to apply a positive Y delta and set his `physicsBody.dynamic` property to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mass and damping can be problematic for characters. Here's how I would set up your player dynamics for jumping:

```
physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(self.size.width, self.size.height))
physicsBody?.dynamic = true
physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
physicsBody?.restitution = 0.0
physicsBody?.friction = 0.0
physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0.0
physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.0
physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
```

When the player jumps, apply an impulse to the `physicsBody`:

```
physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 50.0))
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a go - though the issue is not so much jumping its when he's standing still on the corner of the block. the screen kind of wobbles (if that makes any sense!) ;)

Comment: Those settings should eliminate the wobble effect...good luck!

Comment: Yeah that pretty much worked, reset everything back to 0, added a small amount of mass and adjusted the amount of impulse, now the wobble has gone, thanks .